# A differential equation with "$xy$" term

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to find the general solution of 
$$c_1xy+c_2xy\frac{dy}{dx}+c_3=0$$

Where $c_1,\ c_2,\ c_3$ are constants

Comment: @macydanim : Can this be solved by Laplace transform?